# how to display php for each database return result of 3 records in a bootstrap 3 col-sm-4 view in one row

Tags: php, html

My program is fetching 3 customer records from database in PHP language.i want to show the return result from database in a bootstrap
 grid view like 3 col of `col-sm-4` in one row. Right now, it shows all
 the result in one vertical line.Next thing i want is if have more
 records, then the next record should show in next line and allow only
3 records in one line every time i fetch records from database.
 Looking for the solution.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0px auto;height:auto;border:1px solid yellow;">


@foreach($reviews as $review)

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>name is:- {{$review->name}}</div>
    <div>course is:-{{$review->course}}</div>
    <div>designation is:-{{$review->designation}}</div>
    <div>company is:-{{$review->company}}</div>
    <div>comments:-{{$review->comments}} </div>
    <div>status:{{$review->status}} </div>
    <div>priority:{{$review->priority}}</div>
    <div>review date:-{{$review->review_date}}</div>

    <?php
        $image =stripslashes($review->image);
    ?>
    <div>images:<img src='{{asset("$image")}}'></div>

    </div>
</div>


</div>


@endforeach


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 6</div>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

This will add 3 columns in each row for N number of data automatically!

Comment: incomplete answer....need complete answer...it will include php databse coding and code to covert it into bootstrap grid view of 3 col-sm-4 in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `row` outside of the loop as shown below
Also, I'm not sure why you have a `col-sm-12` and a `col-sm-4`? I'm sure that will confuse things

```
<div class="row">

@foreach($reviews as $review)


<!--<div class="col-sm-12"> -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>name is:- {{$review->name}}</div>
    <div>course is:-{{$review->course}}</div>
    <div>designation is:-{{$review->designation}}</div>
    <div>company is:-{{$review->company}}</div>
    <div>comments:-{{$review->comments}} </div>
    <div>status:{{$review->status}} </div>
    <div>priority:{{$review->priority}}</div>
    <div>review date:-{{$review->review_date}}</div>

    <?php
        $image =stripslashes($review->image);
    ?>
    <div>images:<img src='{{asset("$image")}}'></div>

    </div>
<!--    </div> -->

@endforeach

</div>
```

Comment: Oh, well, I'm so sorry I wasted your precious time. Perhaps you should head on over to [elance.com](https://www.elance.com/) and post your question there instead.